# Depreciation functions with classes not working

Tags: c++, validation, class

I am writing a program that is has a single and double depreciation function in a class called Asset. I am having trouble on the double depreciation function and how to implement it into my class. Also, any suggestions on how to vailidate the user input (i.e. no negatives, no zero, and only a character when asked for a character)? Here is my main, class and class header files.

When i run this program and try to use the double depreciation function, it only uses the straight line one. It ignores the double function in the asset class. why is that? Also, in my main when someone inputs an invalid input, it does the if loop but it then continues with the rest of main, how do I get it to go back to the top of the do while loop?

```
// Depreciation.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Asset.h"
#include <limits>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
char choice;


int main()
{

double c;
double s;
double l;
int y = 0;
bool wrongdata = false;

//normal input task; welcome message, input of 3 fields and output features -  with full data validation

cout << "Welcome to the Depreciation calculator!"<<endl;
do{

    cout << "Please enter an Asset Cost: " << endl;
    cin >> c;
    if (!cin.good())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout<<"Please input a correct value" << endl;
        wrongdata = true;

    }
    if (c == 0)
    {
        cout << "Thanks for using my program!" << endl;
        break;

    }

    cout<< "Please enter the Salvage Value: " << endl;
    cin >> s;
    if (!cin.good())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Please input a correct value" << endl;
        wrongdata = true;
    }
    if (s == 0)
    {
        cout << "Thanks for using my program!"<<endl;
        break;
    }
    cout << "Please enter the Asset life (in years): " << endl;
    cin >> l;
    if (!cin.good())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Please input a correct value" << endl;
        wrongdata = true;
    }
    if (l == 0)
    {

        cout << "Thanks for using my program!" << endl;
        break;
    }

    Asset a = Asset(c, s, l);
    cout << "The annual depreciation is equal to " << a.getAnnualDep() << " for Straight-Line and \n" << a.getDDDep(y) << " for one year of Double Declining" << endl;

    cout << "Would you like to see a depreciation schedule for Straight-Line, DDL, or Neither? (S/D/N)" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    choice = toupper(choice);
    if (choice = 'S')
    {
        cout << "Year   Start Value Depreciation    End Value" << endl;
        for (int i = 1; i <= a.getorigLife(); i++)
        {

            cout << i << "\t\t" << a.getBegBal(i) << "\t\t" << a.getAnnualDep() << "\t\t" << a.getEndBal(i) << endl;
        }

    }
    else if (choice = 'D')
    {
        cout << "Year   Start Value Depreciation    End Value" << endl;
        for (int j = 1; j <= a.getorigLife(); j++)
        {
            cout << j << "\t\t" << a.getDDBBal(j) << "\t\t" << a.getDDDep(y) << "\t\t" << a.getDDEBal(j) << endl;
        }

    }
    else if (choice = 'N')
    {
        cout << "Thanks for using my program" << endl;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Could not understand your input";
        wrongdata = true;
    }

} while (wrongdata);

system("pause");
return 0;
}


//asset class
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Asset.h"




Asset::Asset(double c, double s, int L)
{
ocost = c;
osalv = s;
oLife = L;
anndep = (c - s) / L;
double SLrate = (100.0 / L)/100;
DDanndep = (2 * SLrate) * c;
double DDrate = (2 * SLrate);


//declare arrays for starting and ending values
bbal = new double[oLife];
ebal = new double[oLife];
DDebal = new double[oLife];
DDbbal = new double [oLife];

//calculate straight line depreciation
bbal[0] = ocost;
DDbbal[0] = ocost;

    for (int i = 0; i < oLife; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            bbal[i] = ebal[i - 1];
        }

        ebal[i] = bbal[i] - anndep;

    }

 //calculate double depreciation



    for (int j = 0; j < oLife; j++)
    {
        if (j > 0)
        {
            DDbbal[j] = DDebal[j - 1];
        }

        DDebal[j] = DDbbal[j] - (DDbbal[j] * DDrate);
        DDbbal = DDebal;


    }



}

double Asset::getAnnualDep()
{

return anndep;
}
double Asset::getOrigCost()
{

return ocost;
}
double Asset::getOrigSalvage()
{
return osalv;
}
int Asset::getorigLife()
{
return oLife;
}
double Asset::getBegBal(int y)
{
return bbal[y - 1];
}
double Asset::getEndBal(int y)
{
return ebal[y - 1];

}
double Asset::getDDDep(int y)
{
return DDanndep;
}
double Asset::getDDBBal(int y)
{
return DDbbal[y - 1];
}
double Asset::getDDEBal(int y)
{
return DDebal[y - 1];
}

Asset::~Asset()
{
}

//class header
#pragma once
class Asset
{
public:
Asset(double Cost, double Salvage, int Life); //constructor
~Asset(void); //destructor 

double getOrigCost(), getOrigSalvage(), getAnnualDep();
double getBegBal(int year), getEndBal(int year), getDDBBal(int year), getDDEBal(int year), getDDDep(int year);
int getorigLife();
char choice;

private:

double ocost, osalv, anndep, DDanndep;
int oLife;
double* bbal;
double* ebal;
double*DDebal;
double*DDbbal;


};
```

Comment: some more specific question?

Answer (score 1):

Note that in c++ `=` is assignment and `==` is comparison.

In your if statements like this one:

```
if (choice = 'S')
```

You are assigning 'S' to `choice` and then checking if it is non-zero.

Change it to:

```
if (choice == 'S')
```

Comment: wow, that fixed the double function, thanks! I always get assignment and comparision mixed up. The depreciation value is still the same every time, though.

Comment: How do I emplement my depreciation per year (DDanndep) into the for loop for double depreciation?